save plotly graph objects as PNG
I am trying to save a graph objects fig as a PNG (or any other format) but it seems to hang and not do anything
I have tried
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(
    data=[go.Bar(x=[1, 2, 3], y=[1, 3, 2])],
    layout=go.Layout(
        title=go.layout.Title(text="A Figure Specified By A Graph Object")
    )
)

fig.show()

and then try to export this way (according to the plotly guide
. Actually i have tried the code they have there and same result: no errors and seems to run forever.
fig.write_image("fig1.png")

I tried running the write_image with engine='kaleido' or 'orca' but always gives me nothing and just seems to run forever.
Any ideas or direction i should look at?
Thanks,J

did you remove the fig.show() when using fig.save_image()?

Even with fig.show() it works for me. (When I close the figure)

fig.write_image("fig1.png") won't execute until you close the displayed image...put fig.save_image() first then fig.show()

As you mentioned i have tried 'fig.write_image("fig1.png")' (so no fig.show()) still hangs. Maybe it's not finding kaleido or orca? Although i have tried importing them and it seems to import with no problems
